# Linux arp cache timeout values

Tags: linux, kernel, arp

I'm trying to configure sane values for the Linux kernel arp cache timeout, but I can't find a detailed explanation as to how they work anywhere. Even the kernel.org documentation doesn't give a good explanation, I can only find recommended values to alleviate overflow.

Here is an example of the values I have:

```
net.ipv4.neigh.default.gc_thresh1 = 128
net.ipv4.neigh.default.gc_thresh2 = 512
net.ipv4.neigh.default.gc_thresh3 = 1024
```

Now, from what I've gathered so far:

- gc_thresh1 is the number of arp entries allowed before the garbage collector starts removing any entries at all.
- gc_thresh2 is the soft-limit, which is the number of entries allowed before the garbage collector actively removes arp entries.
- gc_thresh3 is the hard limit, where entries above this number are aggressively removed.

Now, if I understand correctly, if the number of arp entries goes beyond gc_thresh1 but remains below gc_thresh2, the excess will be removed periodically with an interval set by gc_interval.

My question is, if the number of entries goes beyond gc_thresh2 but below gc_thresh3, or if the number goes beyond gc_thresh3, how are the entries removed?
In other words, what does "actively" and "aggressively" removed mean exactly? I assume it means they are removed more frequently than what is defined in gc_interval, but I can't find by how much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time when there is a forced garbage collection of entries, `last_flush` field is updated in the neighbor table, `neigh_table`.

Forced garbage collection of entries happens if one of the following conditions are met:

- Number of entries in the table is greater than `gc_thresh3`
- Number of entries in the table is greater than `gc_thresh2`, and time since `last_flush` is greater than or equal to `5 HZ`

When a forced garbage collection of entries is requested, entries that meet both the following criteria are discarded:

- Nobody refers to the entry
- Entry is not permanent

A periodic work, `neigh_periodic_work` tries to free unreferenced entries if the total number of entries is greater than `gc_thresh1`.

**Source:** Linux kernel source, [neighbour.c](https://raw.github.com/torvalds/linux/v3.11/net/core/neighbour.c)

Comment: OK, I'm not a developer so let me try to see if I understand correctly.

Entries less than gc_thresh1 are left alone.

Entries above gc_thresh1, but below gc_thresh2 are periodically garbage collected with a frequency set by gc_interval.

Entries above gc_thresh2 but below gc_thresh3 are garbage collected every 5 seconds.

Entries above gc_thresh3 are garbage collected immediately, triggered by not by a periodical check, but by the event of adding a new entry.
Is that accurate?

Comment: That sounds correct from what I observed in the source code.